# Classic ASP integrated with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

I have a classic asp project and a teammate created a new functionality, but it's in asp.net mvc. I also know how to work with mvc, but I never used classic asp and mvc together.

For example, is it possible, in this classic asp project, to have a link that will redirect to a mvc page on the same project?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can have a link point to any other page you'd like regardless of technology. Likewise for a redirect. To redirect in classic ASP, use `Response.Redirect`

Comment: One more vote to support what David and Dinah said - I tried it myself and it just works!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, the pages (and that term is used lightly in the MVC side of things) can link between each other without any problems.  Now, any built-in authentication or session management or anything like that will be considerably more challenging, but if all the sites need to do is link to each other then they can do this like any other two websites.  The ASP pages can host manually-crafted (vs. HtmlHelper-crafted) links to the MVC actions, and can host forms that post values to the MVC actions (provided the field names line up properly).

There's nothing inherently special about the MVC actions.  They're just handling HTTP GET/POST requests like anything else.

Comment: But, for example, the teammate created a new mvc project and it has its dll and son on... I just need this dll? I'm a little lost about it...